Clarifying the Use of Binomial Distribution vs. Bayesian Theorem in Bridge
I am exploring probability concepts as they apply to the game of bridge and am seeking some clarification on when to use binomial distribution and when to apply Bayesian theorem. My understanding is that binomial distribution calculates the probability of an event across a number of independent trials, which seems less suited for dynamic scenarios where game conditions change with each card played.
However, Bayesian theorem appears more appropriate for updating probabilities based on new information, such as cards played by opponents.
I would appreciate if you could help with the following:
In bridge, under what circumstances should one use the binomial distribution compared to the Bayesian theorem?
How is Bayesian updating applied in the context of bridge to adjust the probabilities of what cards remain in opponents' hands as the game unfolds?
Thank you for your insights!
